# Using a Azure Virtual Machine Scale set for publishing to Private Endpoint managed App Service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, private, endpoint

I'm trying to set up a hosted agent using Azure Virtual Machine Scale set for doing as the title portrays.
However, setting up the VMSS without a public IP address (I dont want a public IP address since all the publishing from DevOps is made with this IP address and get blocked by SCM in the Private Endpoint) puts all my pipelines in queue not finding a suitable host to take care of the work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team. You can create a Virtual Machine Scale Set without a public IP by selecting “No” for the load balancer option as below:

[image]